# Sci-fi fantasy game with a durian consumable that ended with the MC getting abducted by aliens

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I don't remember much about this game as I played when I was rather young, but I remember really enjoying it, so I'd like to play it again. I believe it was a side-scroller game and it was either on Armor Games or Miniclip.

As for the actual content of the game I don't remember much but I do know the game ended with the MC getting abducted by aliens and that there was a durian consumable. It was probably a Flash game but I'm not certain.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Are there any other details you remember that you can [edit] in? What was the actual gameplay like? How did you control the playable character? What are the requirements for the game ending and getting abducted (as in, how would you _win_)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking about Phoneotopia. It was a game from 2014 that could be found on Armorgames

[image]

The game was about the orphan Gale who lived on Earth in the far future.

You fought the first boss by shooting Durian fruits at it

[image: The bossfight]

In the end everyone gets kidnapped by aliens.

[image: Kidnapped by aliens]

Comment: You are an inspiration to us all if this is correct. Identifying it with so little details.

Comment: There's also a remake on Steam - Phoenotopia Awakening

Comment: Durians as a weapon rather than a consumable makes a lot more sense to most people who have ever attempted to eat one.  They are famously an "acquired taste" in some regions whose appeal most of the rest of the world cannot comprehend.